# Solaris snoop on SSL headers

Tags: ssl, solaris, snoop

Is there a way to snoop (on Solaris) SSL headers ( I don't actually need to capture SSL data ) so that I can ensure SSL is not blocked by any firewalls before entering my server.

Answer (score 1):

In real-time? If not, then you could just use `tcpdump` to a file and then copy the resulting file locally where you can view it with something like Wireshark.

Or you could just use `tcpdump -X ...` or `tcpdump -A ...` to see the actual live packets (it won't decode the SSL header fields.

There is also a command-line tool called `ssldump` which can capture the headers (and more, if you supply it the keying material, but that seems out of scope for what you require).

Comment: hi thanks. Yes, real time if possible. the thing is, we could not install tcpdump/ssldump. thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `openssl`:

```
openssl s_client -host yourhost -port yourport
```

for example

```
openssl s_client -host webserver -port 443
```

This requires no changes on the server you are trying to connect to.